# Webform entity select submission displaying different result than element

Tags: webforms

I have a webform in Drupal 8 with an entity select element. The element is populated from an entity reference view. I have a book content type with information about the book such as title and author. I also have a field collection in book containing more specific details such as ISBN and format. The entity reference view displays title-isbn-format. For example:

Dune - 9780441013593 - Paperback

Dune - 9780143111580 - Hardcover

I applied the view entity reference patch posted [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2174633). The form correctly displays the output of the view. How do I get the same display in the form submission? If I set the form display to value and select Dune paperback the result is "MyBookFieldCollection 0 of Dune (9)."

I tried using tokens but I can only get the field collection info, not the book info.

Here is the source for the element:

```
book_title:
  '#type': entity_select
  '#title': 'Book Title'
  '#select2': true
  '#format': custom
  '#format_html': '[webform_submission:values:book_title:node:title] - [webform_submission:values:book_title:entity:field_isbn_13] - [webform_submission:values:book_title:entity:field_format]'
  '#format_text': '[webform_submission:values:book_title:node:title] - [webform_submission:values:book_title:entity:field_isbn_13] - [webform_submission:values:book_title:entity:field_format]'
  '#target_type': field_collection_item
  '#selection_handler': views
  '#selection_settings':
    view:
      view_name: entity_reference_for_form
      display_name: entity_reference_1
      arguments: {  }
```

This correctly displays the ISBN and book format but not the book title.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired result for the book title by using twig and string manipulation.

I noticed {{ item.label }} returns MyBookFieldCollection 0 of Dune. MyBookFieldCollection is the name of the field collection and 0 represents the selected item. There will not be more than five items in a given collection. I can remove the start of the string using {{ item.label[27:] }} and this returns a value of Dune.

Here is the modified element source:

```
book_title:
  '#type': entity_select
  '#title': 'Book Title'
  '#select2': true
  '#format': custom
  '#format_html': '{{ item.label[27:] }} - [webform_submission:values:book_title:entity:field_isbn_13] - [webform_submission:values:book_title:entity:field_format]'
  '#format_text': '{{ item.label[27:] }} - [webform_submission:values:book_title:entity:field_isbn_13] - [webform_submission:values:book_title:entity:field_format]'
  '#target_type': field_collection_item
  '#selection_handler': views
  '#selection_settings':
    view:
      view_name: entity_reference_for_form
      display_name: entity_reference_1
      arguments: {  }
```

This outputs Dune - 9780441013593 - Paperback in the form submission.